# Utilities for comparing different JPEG compression engines?

Tags: image-processing

I'm looking to do some statistical analysis on the effect on an image of various compression systems, with the end-goal of hopefully being able to determine [which is a recompressed version of which](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27328883/determine-which-of-a-set-of-images-has-been-recompressed-resaved-the-least). To do this, I need to be able to feed a set of test-images through a assortment of different image compressors.

Are there any resources for this sort of thing? Is there anything like a website where I can submit something, and get versions recompressed via an assortment of compressors?

Alternatively, is there any good information on which compressors are commonly used? I'm realizing I don't even know to what extent most of the image editors out there share code.

Comment: As PNG is lossless, what are you aiming to do there?

Comment: @PhilipKendall - Good point. I could have sworn it had a lossy option, Whoops?

Comment: PNG doesn't have a lossy option but IIRC you can adjust how aggressive the compression algorithm is on some implementations.

Comment: @PhilipKendall - Good point, moved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm basically going to answer my own question: No.

There are no decent facilities for comparing JPEG compression libraries.

Additionally, I did some [further experimentation](https://github.com/fake-name/ImProcessing-Scratchpad/tree/master/entropyCode) which effectively invalidated the hypothesis that produced my desire for a comparative analysis in the first place, so the whole question is somewhat moot at this point.

I did a bunch of testing with the compressor used in [`PIL`](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/) (which is `libjpeg`):
[image]

This is over the corpus of the [USC-SIPI](http://sipi.usc.edu/database/) image test set, looking at the average entropy per pixel as a function of various compression ratios.

I did a writeup [here](https://github.com/fake-name/ImProcessing-Scratchpad/tree/master/entropyCode).

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if you are looking at different compression options strictly for JPEG or if you are interested in other formats with lossy compression.

But in any case, I think Imagemagick would be a good starting point. It is a command line based tool and there is also PythonMagick that I never used, but which allows using IM directly from Python scripts.

Here is some reading about JPEG options in IM:
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/

And here is a list of supported file formats, in case you consider supporting other formats like Jpeg2000 etc.:
https://subversion.imagemagick.org/subversion/ImageMagick/branches/ImageMagick-6.5.5/www/formats.html

I think it would be a good idea to also test [webp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebP) image format introduced by Google that some believes is superior to jpeg

Edit: Reading through the resources I linked above I found [JPEG online laboratory](http://sylvana.net/jpeg-lab.html) that might be useful for your work.

Comment: I was interested in **exclusively** the differences between different JPEG systems. As I said, my end goal is to be able to automate the determination of whether one image is a recompressed version of another. My image corpus is probably 90% JPEG, 10% PNG, and basically nothing else. No one really uses webp images or anything like that.

Comment: Also, again, I don't need information on the analysis part (I understand that fairly well). I'm **/only/** looking for information regarding what varies between different JPEG libraries.

Comment: Anyways, apparently ImageMagick uses `libjpeg`, which is also used by [`PIL`](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/), so I've basically already got that covered anyways.

Comment: The IM documentation I linked above mentions jpegqran/jpegtrans (http://www.jpegclub.org) that use different compression. I believe IM can be recompiled with jpeg-turbo (which is faster, but I don't know if the codec is the same or not).

Answer (score -2):

Use difference blending in photoshop - original image in a bottom layer, changed image in a top layer. Everything that's not black will be changed from the original image.

Also: If I remember well there's no such thing as "different compressors" - JPEG is one strictly described compression algorithm. To simplify: implementations differ only in how value X on your compression scroll bar translates to the compression strength in the actual algorithm, but the algorithm is always the same.

Comment: "JPEG is one strictly described compression algorithm". So why does the [GIMP](http://docs.gimp.org/2.8/en/images/using/export-jpeg-dialog.png) give me "Optimize", "Smoothing", "Subsampling" and "DCT method"?

Comment: *Sigh*. 1. There are [very, VERY much different](http://fotoforensics.com/tutorial-ela.php) (Look at the section labeled "Rainbowing") approaches and different choices with regard to constants and such in the design of the compression system. The JPEG standard may be well-defined, but there are **LOTS** of tuneable parameters for the actual compression that are all well within the standard, and vary from software to software.

Comment: 2. I'm doing *statistical analyses*. I'm not using photoshop, I'm using a script I wrote that directly quantifies the entropy-per-pixel. Just "looking" at something has basically zero scientific rigor.

Comment: Basically, I'm seeking to be able to determine, with decent accuracy (99%+), if/which image out of two is closer to the original, in an automated manner.

Comment: Philip Kendall - all of these are parts of standard JPG specification. # Fake Name - you can perform statistical analysis on difference between original and modified image just fine.

Comment: You're missing the point, there are a lot of tuneable options in the JPG specification and they vary between different implementations. Some applications expose some of them (GIMP), some have hard-coded values (Photoshop). Claiming the *only* thing that can vary is the compression degree is flat-out wrong.

Comment: Basically, I need a decent corpus of images compressed with different tunable parameters to do any sort of analysis.

Comment: Yea, yea, I get it just fine, thank you, no reason to write 20 messages on the same thing. If you have a basic problem with performing analysis of difference between two images - ask on stackoverflow, perhaps there someone can guide you through the basics of programming. Here we answer questions related to photography, not statistical analysis of images. I answered you stuff related to the topic of this stackexchange. Otherwise - you're asking in a wrong place.

Comment: Everybody: keep it polite.

Comment: I would argue that understanding image compression is a core part of modern photography. If there is a stack exchange better suited to the question, I'm open to moving the question.

Comment: Feel free to argue, but not with me, even though I disagree. But as said - discussions about implementing statistical analysis of images is something that belongs more to stackoverflow than anything directly related to photography.

Comment: @MarcinWolny - I asked on StackOverflow and got closed. So not, it apparently does not. Anyways, I know how to do the analysis, that parts easy. It's getting an idea of what's out there that is hard.